# как изменить требуемый разряд двоичного представления числа

Tags: c, функции, битовые-операции

Дано число 1 байт, без знака. Написать функцию типа void, позволяющую вывести информацию об 2
разряде двоичного представления введенного числа и инвертировать его (установить,
если был сброшен, и сбросить, если был установлен).

Я понял как вывести число в двоичном представлении. Как же мне теперь изменить 2 разряд числа?

```
void out(unsigned char* num)
{
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (*num & (1 << i))
        {
            printf("1");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    unsigned char num=17;
    out(&num);
}
```

Comment: Передаваемое число может быть не однобайтовым для `unsigned char`, "тип функции" не может быть `void`

Comment: почему тип функции не может быть void? программа же запускается, и предупреждений насчет этого никаких не делает

Comment: `void` - возвращаемый функцией тип, а не тип функции

Comment: Я так понял вас просят вывести только 2й разряд. А инвертировать его можно с помощью xor (операторы `^` или `^=`) с числом у которого установлена 1 в нужном разряде

Comment: if (*num ^ 239)

Comment: 11101111 - 239 в двоичном представлении. Я  правильно понял? На втором разряде нахордится 1, т.е оно нам подходит

Comment: @Mike а как теперь сделать так чтобы вывести только 2й разряд?

Comment: Я не знаю что означает "2й разряд", откуда ведется счет и с 0 или с 1 ? Если с младших разрядов и с 1 то `x ^ (1 << 1)` (или кратко `x ^ 2`) инвертирует именно второй разряд. А вывести его просто. Вы же все число в цикле сейчас сдвигами раскладываете, так же сдвигом можете, только без цикла один разряд получить и все

Comment: @rendy, *`"Как же мне теперь изменить 2 разряд числа?"`*  Для инверсии бита в той же void функции можете написать в конце `(*num) ^= 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void out2(unsigned char c)
{
    putchar(c&0x02 ? '1' : '0');
}

unsigned char inv2(unsigned char c)
{
    return c^0x02;
}
```

Если разряды считать от младшего, и младший считать первым...

На всякий случай - 0x02 не потому 2, что второй разряд, а потому, что это число из всех нулевых разрядов, кроме второго... Для третьего было бы 0x04.

Comment: Вообще, для n-го бита можно написать `c ^ (1 << n)`

Comment: @avp Можно. Но я предельно упрощал :)

Comment: Ну, этот комментарий не вам, а им -)